Flink job writing to hive partitioned table throws "Partition already exists: Partition"
I have a flink job written in java to sink datastream to a partitioned table in hive(external table).
While the data is being sink to table, the partition committer throws the below exception
INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - PartitionCommitter -> Sink: end (1/1) (10f544509ec5e276e07b3380efe875dc_0318c13852577e097f3e0640d3da1fc9_0_1) switched from RUNNING to FAILED on container_e149_1726213205042_1280_01_000009 @ ftest-cdp01.360t.com (dataPort=35365).
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.AlreadyExistsException: Partition already exists: Partition

2024-11-02 09:04:40,674 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Job insert-into_hive.flink_hive.cur_sst_description,hive.flink_hive.cur_streaming_quotes (593407f65212574a91be108f4eb2782a) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.

Flink job uses flink-connector-hive_2.12.
I am deploying the flink job with multiple parellelism for streamingFilewrite and partitioncommitter. In the hive logs also, I can see the same exception for Partition already exists exception.
DDL for hive partition table is given below. Here value for coly is the recieved date time
create external table if not exists tablex (....)
PARTITIONED BY (coly string) 
TBLPROPERTIES("sink.partition-commit.policy.kind"="metastore")

With this behaviour, I am little confused if am missing any configurations. I am expecting that even though the parition exists, it would go ahead and alter the partition without trying to creatae a new one as the job is  run with multiple parellelism.
I have tried deploying with single and multiple parellelism but both yields the same Parition already exists paritition.
